# Derivative of a matrix with respect to elements of another matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, multivariable-calculus, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

I am trying to take the "derivative" of a matrix $M = ABB^TA^T$ with respect to the inner matrix $B$, where $A$ is $n\times n$ and $B$ is $n\times m$ with $m \leq n$.

In other words, looking for a closed form solution to $\frac{\partial M_{ab}}{\partial B_{ij}}$ for all $1\leq a,b,i \leq n$ and $1\leq j \leq m$

Eventually, the goal would be to use this to find the derivative of the sum of all elements of $M$ with respect to the elements of $B$. So if $\mathbf{1}$ is the $n\times 1$ vector of $1$'s, then let:

$f(B) = \sum_{a=1}^n \sum_{b=1}^n M_{ab} = \mathbf{1}^T A B B^T A^T \mathbf{1}$

And my end goal is to find $\frac{\partial f(B)}{\partial B_{ij}}$. Of course, since the derivative of a sum is the sum of derivatives, I should be able to find the full solution from a closed-form expression for $\frac{\partial M_{ab}}{\partial B_{ij}}$

This seems like it should have a simple solution but I have been stuck on it for a while. Any help is welcome and appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a colon to denote the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$$A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB) = {\rm Tr}(AB^T) = B:A$$
and use it to rewrite the cost function. Then calculate its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
f &= {\rm Tr}({\tt1}^TABB^TA^T{\tt1}) \\
  &= {\rm Tr}(A^T{\tt1}{\tt1}^TABB^T) \\
  &= A^T{\tt1}{\tt1}^TA:BB^T \\
df
 &= A^T{\tt1}{\tt1}^TA:(dB\,B^T+B\,dB^T) \\
 &= 2A^T{\tt1}{\tt1}^TA:dB\,B^T \\
 &= 2A^T{\tt1}{\tt1}^TAB:dB \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial B}
 &= 2A^T{\tt1}{\tt1}^TAB \\
}$$
**NB:**   The properties of the trace allow terms in a colon product to be shuffled around, e.g.
$$A:BC \;=\; AC^T:B \;=\; B^TA:C \;=\; etc.$$
Also recall that the trace of a *scalar* quantity is equal to the quantity itself.

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Are there any assumptions being made on $B$ when reducing the addition on the right side of the differential? (From $dB B^T + BdB^T$ to $2dB B^T$)

Comment: It follow from the Frobenius-specific rule
$$A^T:B={\rm Tr}(AB)=A:B^T$$
and the fact that multiplication distributes over addition, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
A:(B+B^T)&=(A:B)+(A:B^T)\\&=(A:B)+(A^T:B)\\&=(A+A^T):B\\&=2A:B\\
}$$
The above assumes that $A$ is symmetric, but $B$ is not.

Comment: Oh, I see. $A$ in the original problem is not necessarily symmetric, but if I’m understanding your comment, it only needs to be true that $A^T 11^T A$ is symmetric. Is this correct?

Comment: That's correct. If you work with Frobenius products frequently, the following are worth memorizing
$$\eqalign{
{\rm sym}(A) &= \tfrac{1}{2}(A+A^T) \\
{\rm skew}(A) &= \tfrac{1}{2}(A-A^T) \\
A:{\rm sym}(B) &= B:{\rm sym}(A) \\
A:{\rm skew}(B) &= B:{\rm skew}(A) \\
}$$

Comment: I don’t work with Frobenius products very much.. but this conversation has got me thinking that I should. Thanks again for all the useful information